# Why won't images show up on my html website

Tags: html, css, image

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 



<html>
<title>Title</title>
    <head>
        <link href="stylesz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Website description" />
        <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="tags, tags, tags" />
        <meta name="LANGUAGE" content="EN" />

    <style>
    .header {
        background-color:orange;
        color:white;
        margin:20px;
        padding:20px;
    }   
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
        <h1>Mywebsite</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="maincontent" align="center">
        <p>Content!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="logo" align="center">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png">
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

There is just a small broken page icon where the image should be. I have not started up my webpage yet.

Comment: Seem so show the wiki sphere just fine: http://jsbin.com/wucoyetixi/1/edit

Comment: I'd assume the problem is with your server setup. As the html code itself works fine.

Comment: The link above is fine - is that the img you're trying to display or some other one? What do you mean you haven't "started up" your page yet? Are you viewing a local copy in your browser?

Comment: Yes i'm viewing a local copy in my browser

Comment: is it because i'm viewing a local copy of my html in the browser? Do I need to use an actual file image from my computer instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this HTML code, it could be that your website is denied to connect to the web. Please check your browser and/or server settings :)

Comment: is it because i'm viewing a local copy of my html in the browser? Do I need to use an actual file image from my computer instead?

Comment: I made a local copy of your html and it went out to the wiki site and  pulled the image.  Copy and paste your above html into a new file and see if the new file works.